# SPI slave-mode on imx8qmlpddr4arm2 board using yocto

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, yocto, spi, nxp-microcontroller

I am developing an SPI slave-mode driver for a imx8qmlpddr4amr2 board, but I am facing problems. I am using Yocto Morty, and Linux kernel version 4.9 does not support the SPI controller operating in slave mode.  So I am taking the SPI layer of the more recent kernel and adapting it to this one.
The result is that my slave controller waits forever to receive bytes even if the other board is sending data.

So my question is: has anyone built an SPI slave-mode driver on the imx8qmlpddr4arm2 board using Yocto?
If yes, which version of Yocto have you used?
Is it possible to use Yocto Sumo on my board?
Or if it is only possible to use Morty, does a patch exist?

Do I need to do something particular on the Device Tree files, like clock, interrupt lines?
Do they have to be treated differently from when I use master-mode driver?

Thank you for the answers, and sorry for bad English!

Comment: To be clear, you want to use the SPI controller of the SoC in slave mode (rather than master mode)?

Comment: Yes, in slave mode!